# Rendering an array of the same sprite at different locations

Tags: c++, for-loop, sprite

I am trying to recreate Space Invaders and I am having trouble with getting my invader sprite to display in a row instead of on top of each other. I have a STRUCT called Sprite that contains the x position, y position, width, height, and color and I am passing that information into a custom function that draws the sprite. Everything works if I am just creating one sprite. But I want to create multiple ones (say 5 for testing purposes). So I created an array of the Sprite structure and in a For-Loop I tried to change the x position of each element within the array and than use the custom function to draw an element of the array at each iteration of the loop but for some reason I am not getting the proper result. I can see in the debugger that the x position is in fact being changed but everything is still getting drawn on top of each other I think.

```
struct INVADER
{
    int xPos = 100;
    int yPos;
    int width;
    int height;
    D3DCOLOR color;

    INVADER()
    {
        xPos; 
        yPos;
        width = 64;
        height = 64;
        color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255);
    }

};


INVADER invaderArmy[5];

    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        //invaderArmy->xPos = 100;

        invaderArmy[index].xPos *= index;

        Draw_And_Rotate_Sprite(invaderImage, invaderArmy[index].xPos);

    }
```

Comment: Does your for-loop get executed more than once?  Because you are multiplying each INVADER's xPos by the value of `index` every time you execute the for-loop, which means that after a few iterations, only your first two INVADERS (which have their xPos multiplied by 0 and 1 each time, respectively) are likely to remain on-screen... invaders #2, #3, and #4 will quickly accumulate really huge xPos values.   I think maybe you want to change that line to `invaderArmy[index].xPos = (index * 100);` instead.

Comment: Also, from the code presented, it look like you never set yPos to any value at all, which means each `INVADER`'s yPos value could be any value (depending on whatever leftover data happened to be present at that RAM location beforehand).  You need to initialize your variables before using them, or you will get unexpected results.

Comment: As mentioned in my reply to Hydra Zerg below, changing the line of code from `invaderArmy[index].xPos *= index;` to `invaderArmy[index].xPos = (index * 100);` worked. It makes since now that I am looking at it. I will be setting my yPos parameter though. I Intend to just default my position parameters to 0. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm only wiriting here because i dont have 50 rep to comment.

Shouldn't the parameter from the called `Draw_And_Rotate_Sprite()` function be `invaderArmy[index]` instead of `invaderArmy[index].xPos` ?

Also there isn't a problem i can see in the code presented. Please show us the `Draw_And_Rotate_Sprite()` function definition.

Comment: I think the reason why I don't want to do that is because I am using my Draw_And_Rotate_Sprite() function for all of my sprites. So at times I may not be passing in an array of object like I did this time. But as Jeremy suggested changing this line of code from `invaderArmy[index].xPos *= index;` to `invaderArmy[index].xPos = (index * 100);` fixed the problem.